# How to jump between small panels which are inside the "unit testing" panel, in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

When I run unit tests in intellij-IDEA, there are two small panels inside the "test" panel, as following image:

[image]

Suppose the focus is on the right panel, the red vertical line, and I want to jump to the left panel, the position of the green one. How can I do it all by keyboard?

I have to use mouse to do it since I can't find a way. Is it possible?